# Displaying inflated child views in Eclipse UI preview

Tags: android, eclipse, android-xml

I have created a custom ViewGroup that inherits from FrameLayout. Whenever this view is inflated, I want it to automatically inflate and add a child view as the background view. I have accomplished this in the following way:

```
public class CustomViewGroup extends FrameLayout
{
    private View background;
    public CustomViewGroup(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        inflateLayout(context);
    }
    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        inflateLayout(context);
    }
    public CustomViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        inflateLayout(context);
    }

    private void inflateLayout(Context context) 
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        background = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.background, this);
    }

}
```

This works just fine when I am running on an emulator or on a device, but in the Eclipse UI previewer the background child view doesn't get rendered (there are no errors in the log). I would prefer not to have to use "android:background" so that the background view can be edited in the XML.

I assume that the previewer just doesn't know about the child view so it doesn't draw it. Is there some function that I can override so that the child view will be displayed in the previewer?

Comment: As far as I know, that's not possible. The previewer will just display static xml content. Not inflated dynamic views.

Comment: I have noticed that the preview does show any drawing done in OnDraw(Canvas c).  So the previewer does take some execution path through the views that it is provided to generate the preview. I'm wondering if Android has purposefully disabled inflation in the previewer for speed issues.